# Input Dialog Message Box (Windows Phone 8.1 Universal)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How can I show a message box with an input dialog on Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)?

Comment: Probably the same way it's done now in C# for Windows-- Make your own unless referenced VB.NET dlls to get InputBox class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the `<Popup>`-XAML-Tag with a `<TextBox>` inside is working fine.
(same XAML Code on Windows and Windows Phone)

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows Phone Runtime app (but not on Windows) you can use a [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.Aspx) to create a full-screen message box with whatever content you need. This can include input controls.

If you add a new content dialog from the Add New Item... menu it will generate a sample template to input an email address and password. Modify that to fit your input, new one up, then await its ShowAsync like you would a MessageDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Content Dialog dedicated for Windows Phone 8.1 Universal.

Just right click on your Windows Phone 8.1 project in Visual Studio and select add new item -> Content Dialog.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using the <Popup>-XAML-Tag for now